# Multiple monitors with Intel GMA & Radeon HD 5450

Tags: 14.04, graphics, multiple-monitors, intel-graphics

I have two monitors, first monitor is connected by D-sub to Radeon HD5450. This monitor works well.
Second monitor is connected by D-sub to Intel GMA (integrated graphic on board) and system can't detect this monitor. I can't change connection cable. On windows it worked well, but on Linux I can't solve my problem.

I set in BIOS startup graphic to intel GMA but after OS loading monitor is going to switch to HD5450

**lspci | grep VGA**

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Manhattan [Mobility Radeon HD 5430 Series]
```

**xrand**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 1280 x 1280
DFP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DFP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
CRT1 connected 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 337mm x 270mm
   1280x1024      60.0*+   75.0  
   1280x960       75.0     60.0  
   1280x768       75.0     60.0  
   1280x720       75.0     60.0  
   1024x768       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   1024x600       75.0     70.1     60.0  
   800x600        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   800x480        72.2     75.0     60.3  
   640x480        75.0     72.8     59.9
```

**/etc/X11/xorg.conf**

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "aticonfig Layout"
        Screen      0  "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0" 0 0
EndSection

Section "Module"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "aticonfig-Monitor[0]-0"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "0-CRT1"
        Option      "VendorName" "ATI Proprietary Driver"
        Option      "ModelName" "Generic Autodetecting Monitor"
        Option      "DPMS" "true"
        Option      "PreferredMode" "1280x1024"
        Option      "TargetRefresh" "60"
        Option      "Position" "0 0"
        Option      "Rotate" "normal"
        Option      "Disable" "false"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        Identifier  "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        Driver      "fglrx"
        Option      "Monitor-CRT1" "0-CRT1"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "aticonfig-Screen[0]-0"
        Device     "aticonfig-Device[0]-0"
        DefaultDepth     24
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```